what is wrong with this logarithm code? (new to coding)
int starting ;
int ending ;
float x;

do
{ starting = get_int (" Starting population of llamas? "); }
while (starting < 12);

do
{ ending = get_int (" Ending population of llamas? "); }
while ( ending < starting );

x = log( ending / starting ) / log(13 / 12);
printf (" %f\n ", x);

Running this code leads to no errors, but when i enter a mathematically correct value such as starting=12 & ending =13, this leads me to an output on the terminal as NaN (not a number) or inf (infinite), instead of the correct value of 1. how do i correct this? tysm

Dividing two ints uses integer division, giving an integer result. For example the result of 13 / 12 is 1. You should convert to floating point first, and then divide.

Integer division 13/12 will be 1. so you do log(1) which is 0. So you divide by zero. Use float instead. For instance: log( (double)ending / starting ) / log(13.0 / 12);

@SupportUkraine thx, your line worked, could i enquire why you place (double) instead of (float). & how does the 13.0 instead of 13 work in C ? thanks

@Dylanwee Because double gives better presision than float. On most systems double is 64 bit while float is 32. The rule for floating point calculation is: Always use double unless you have a very good reason for use of float (e.g. a reason could be use of less memory when you need to hold a lot of values in memory)

@SupportUkraine thx man appreciate the clear explanation

@Dylanwee You also asked: " how does the 13.0 instead of 13 work in C ?" In C the type of a number written without a "decimal dot" is int. The type of a number written with a "decimal dot" is double. So 13.0 / 12 will be calculated using double. You could also write it as (double)13 / 12.

It's worth noting, that (double)13 is syntactically a different thing from 13.0. The latter is a double number given explicitly, while the former means 'take an integer value of 13 and convert it to the double type'. Of course compilers typically do the conversion during the compilation phase, so it will not appear in the executable code. As a result the two expressions, although syntactically different, are practically equivalent.
